# linkedlist: insert node at head of linkedlist Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am just learning linkedlists and trying to insert a node at the head.
Here is my code:

```
Node Insert(Node head,int x) {

    Node tmp = new Node();

    if (head == null) {
        head = tmp;
        tmp.data = x;

    }
    tmp.data = x;
    tmp = head;
    tmp.next = head;

    return tmp;
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. My logic:

- Create a new node 'tmp'
- assign that value of 'x' and the reference to tmp would be null
- MAke tmp's next i.e. reference to the head of the linkedlist
- if head is null then tmp's data becomes head's data and tmp's reference become null

Comment: You haven't _Create a new node 'tmp'_.

Comment: `tmp` is always `null` when you try to use it

Comment: Start making the distinction between objects, variables, and references.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if I create Node tmp = new Node() then what is wrong in the rest of my code?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. Please don't change your question like that.

Comment: One of the problems was the null pointer that you mentioned but marking it as a duplicate is not valid at all as it doesn't help me.